# Problem with pygrowup ('Series' object has no attribute 'zscore_for_measurement')

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, attributeerror

I need to calculate z-scores of such measurements as height and weight based on WHO standards. To do so, I want to use the pygrowup package that was designed specifically for that. When typing:

```
data['z_height'] = Calculator.lhfa(df['length'],df.age, df.female)
```

I get an error message:

```
`AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-8c8a5b790d43> in <module>
      3 
      4 
----> 5 df['z_height'] = Calculator.lhfa(df['length'],df.age, df.female) 
      6 df.head()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pygrowup\pygrowup.py in lhfa(self, measurement, age_in_months, sex, height)
    280     def lhfa(self, measurement=None, age_in_months=None, sex=None, height=None):
    281         """ Calculate length/height-for-age """
--> 282         return self.zscore_for_measurement('lhfa', measurement=measurement,
    283                                            age_in_months=age_in_months,
    284                                            sex=sex, height=height)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in
__getattr__(self, name)    5272             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):    5273    return self[name]
-> 5274             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)    5275     5276     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'zscore_for_measurement'
```

Since this is a pretty specific package, there is no much information on Google. The GitHub repository does not seem active and my issue is not addressed there. So I ll be very very appreciative for any advice, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION FROM COMMENTS:**

The sex variable should be "M" or "F", not 1 or 0.

**PREVIOUS ANSWER:**

It appears you are passing a Pandas Series object (`df['length']`) to the Calculator class when it is expecting a Decimal (or similar).

You can cast the Series instance to the desired type, but you also need to provide a single value if there are multiple to the `zscore_for_measurement()` method (which is called from `Calculator.lhfa()`):

```
>>> x = np.array([1, 2, 2.5])
>>> x
array([ 1. ,  2. ,  2.5])
>>> x.astype(int)
array([1, 2, 2])
```

To test, pass a decimal (e.g. 5.5, etc.) in place of the `df['length']` parameter perhaps.

Source code: https://github.com/ewheeler/pygrowup/blob/master/pygrowup/pygrowup.py

Documentation on Pandas Series objects: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html

Documentation on casting Series objects: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.7.0/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html

If this ends up not being the case, I will update my answer.

**EDIT**

You can also try to create (instantiate) a Calculator object, then call the lhfa() method on that object - if might be referencing the "self" from the source code as if it were another (Pandas Series) object. For example:

```
calc = Calculator()
data['z_height'] = calc.lhfa(...)
```

Or, you can also try to call the `zscore_for_measurement()` method directly like so, making sure you pass the 'lhfa' indicator parameter manually:

```
data['z_height'] = Calculator.zscore_for_measurement('lhfa', measurement, age, sex...)
```

Comment: thanks for feedback! I've passed a decimal, but then the error message was that "float has no attribute ..."

Comment: What type of object is data - a regular Python dictionary? Also. what happens if you call the zscore_for_measurement() method directly like so: Calculator.zscore_for_measurement('lhfa', measurement=measurement, age_in_months=age_in_months, sex=sex, height=height)

Comment: Also, you can try creating a Calculator object first - calc = Calculator() then calc.lhfa(...)

Comment: when called directly, it says "zscore_for_measurement() missing 1 required positional argument: 'indicator'". I have a regular stata dateset, imported as pd.read_stata("...")

Comment: idk why it does not see the indicator, which is df.length in my case

Comment: If you call directly, you have to pass 'lhfa' as the indicator parameter - is that present?

Comment: The indicator should be 'lhfa', not a length measurement.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Thanks to you i see the problem!! I need to recode sex values into "M" and "F" instead of 0 1 as I did it before, thanks!